# Separating by SQL unrecognized character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MSSQL. A certain column is returning entries in the following format:

`string1□string2□ □ □□string3□string4□`

I do not know what this character `□` stands for, but I want the query to return `string1` on a column and `string2` on the next column, right next to it and to skip the rest so I can add other columns to the query. Note that it has many rows, all with different strings, but they are all written in the same way. However, I cannot write each string in the statement.

For the sake of definition:

| ID | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | string1a□string2a□ □ □□string3a□string4a□ |
| 2 | string1b□string2b□ □ □□string3b□string4b□ |

Result desired

| ID | string1 | string2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | string1a | string2a |
| 2 | string1b | string2b |

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW64c.png)

Comment: Hi Samuel, what's database are you on?

Comment: please edit question, show the table definition, and query.

Comment: I have edited it, and in my editor the tables are both showing as in the image provided at the end labelled as "example", but when publishing, it doesn't render correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could be a good starting point:

```
select replace(replace('string1□string2□□□string3□string4□','□','|'),'|||','|') 
from dual;
```

Outputs:

```
string1|string2|string3|string4|
```

---

To get just the first 2 columns, you might use something like the below.  This is in plsql though.  For SQL Server you may need to use `CHARINDEX` rather than `INSTR`

```
select substr(string1,1,position) string2
from (select replace(replace('string1□string2□□□string3□string4□','□','|'),'|||','|') string1
        ,instr(replace(replace('string1□string2□□□string3□string4□','□','|'),'|||','|'),'|',1,2) position
    from dual);
```

Outputs:

```
string1|string2|
```

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion on retrieving only the first 2 strings?

Comment: I want to mention that this is for a long report of many entries, all having different strings, so I cannot write the strings myself in the statement.

Comment: Replace 'string1□string2□□□string3□string4□' with name of column.